# Issue with Visual Studio's Report Wizard

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am just starting out using SSRS reports, and having a strange issue. Currently the application I am maintaining, contains 3 projects in visual studio solution. The structure looks something like the following:

```
-- DAL
     Entities.edmx
     Helpers.cs
-- Reports
     Report1.rdlc
     Report2.rdlc
-- Website
     Default.aspx

etc...
```

Now I am trying add a new report with Visual Studio's (2010) reporting wizard into the 'Reports' project. I am trying to add the Helpers.cs (from the DAL project) class as a dataset. However the reporting wizard does not find the Helpers class as a dataset. It seems to find it if I add a report in the 'Website' project though.

I hope this makes sense.
Could anyone please help?

Many thanks